# Build HyperLink within GridView for each row

Tags: c#, gridview, hyperlink

I have a GridView called "BasketGrid" which contains information about products a user has selected for purchase. I have added a HyperLink called "EditProdOpts" to the product options column so that users can return to the product page to make changes before completing the checkout process if need be (The URL is NOT in the database, so I can't make it a HyperLinkField in the GridView).

I currently have a function setup that is supposed to set the correct url for the HyperLink, but it only partly works. At the moment, it sets every instance of the HyperLink to the url of the very last product in the GridView. I am not sure what I am missing, though...

This is the function:

```
    protected string BuildLink(object dataItem)
    {
        string ProductLink = "";
        foreach (GridViewRow basketRow in BasketGrid.Rows)
        {
            BasketItem item = (BasketItem)dataItem;
            if ((item.OrderItemType == OrderItemType.Product))
            {
                HyperLink optionsLink = (HyperLink)basketRow.FindControl("EditProdOpts");
                if (optionsLink != null)
                {
                    optionsLink.NavigateUrl = string.Format("~/Admin/orders/Create/CreateOrderAddProduct.aspx?Action=Edit&UID={0}&LineID={1}&ProdId={2}", _UserId, item.BasketItemId, item.ProductId);
                    ProductLink = optionsLink.NavigateUrl;
                }
            }
        }
        return ProductLink;
    }
```

This is where the HyperLink is in the GridView:

```
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Item">
                        <HeaderStyle CssClass="columnHeader" HorizontalAlign="left" VerticalAlign="top" />
                        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <uc:BasketItemDetail ID="BasketItemDetail1" runat="server" BasketItem="<%# Container.DataItem %>" LinkProducts="false" /><br /><%# Container.DataItem %>
                                <asp:PlaceHolder ID="EditOptPanel" runat="server" Visible='<%# ShowOptionsLink(Container.DataItem) %>'>
                                    <asp:HyperLink ID="EditProdOpts" runat="server" Text="Edit Options" NavigateUrl='<%# BuildLink(Container.DataItem) %>' />
                                </asp:PlaceHolder>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need loop through the rows of the GridView.

Your function will be called once for each row.

You might not need your function at all.  Check out the DataNavigateUrlFormatString property:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hyperlinkfield.datanavigateurlformatstring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx